# Ionic 3 redirect after user In-active in app for some time?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How to we detect user is in-active in ionic application so we can redirect him/her in login page again.

**According to Wesley answer**

```
// idle logout timer set to 10 second
public idleLogoutTimer: number = 10000;

// First execute the timer and wait for hostListener 
onInit() {
  this.restartIdleLogoutTimer();
}   

// Whenever users touch action occure this function will execute.
@HostListener('touchstart')
onTouchStart() {
  this.restartIdleLogoutTimer();
}

// First this will clear timeout then again setTimeout fun and counting start again, After specific time if user did not active then log out function will execute.

restartIdleLogoutTimer() {
 clearTimeout(this.idleLogoutTimer);
   this.idleLogoutTimer = setTimeout(()=>{
   this.logoutUser();
 },60000);
}

logoutUser() {
  // your logout logic here
}
```

Comment: Define "inactive". Like they haven't tapped the screen?

Comment: Yes, If user not tapped screen for some time then I have to redirect to login again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

set a timeout for whatever amount of time you want to consider someone "idle". Then listen to "touchstart" event and trigger the timeout to restart every time the user touches the screen.

In app.component.ts

```
@HostListener('touchstart')
onTouchStart() {
    this.restartIdleLogoutTimer();
}

idleLogoutTimer;

OnInit() {
  restartIdleLogoutTimer();
}

restartIdleLogoutTimer() {
  clearTimeout(this.idleLogoutTimer);
  this.idleLogoutTimer = setTimeout(()=>{
    this.logoutUser();
  },60000);
}

logoutUser() {
  // your logout logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, HostListener working grt, but I did not getting how to set idleLogoutTimer = 12H,  and how system know time is out so execute logout function ?

Comment: Hi I edit my question and explain ur answer to my self 

Comment: 12 Hours? Ok, I had no idea you wanted to to be so long of an idle time. I can think of a solution, but I'll need some time to write it out later.

Comment: Thanks, That would be helpful for me.

Comment: Hii Wesley I used your previous answer and it working fine. please upgrade ur answer so I can accept it. 

Comment: Hii Wesley I also need your suggestion over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64586789/how-to-get-trusted-signing-certificate-for-ionic-app